# Change color of text if value changes, JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="ProductPriceWrap">
                <div class="DetailRow RetailPrice" style="display: none; ">
                    <span class="Label">MSRP:</span>


                </div>

                <div class="DetailRow PriceRow" style="">
                    <div class="Value">
                        <em class="ProductPrice VariationProductPrice">$42.00</em>

                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
```

I need a script that changes the color of the price value to red if it changes. I started by getting the value when the page loads and figured I could do something like, if < original value, style red, but I am still new to JavaScript and cant quite work it out.

Any input is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What causes the price value to change?

Comment: Show  us what you have tried..

Comment: Do you mean if you manually change the price in the HTML?

Comment: I think your Html is wrong, you should add an input field to change the price, How one end user is supposed to change the price inside a div ?

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 I'm not sure that the user is supposed to change the price here.

Answer (score 0):

At first I would at an ID:

```
<em id="price" class="ProductPrice VariationProductPrice">$42.00</em>
```

then you can make something like

```
if ($("#price").text().substr(1) < original_value) {
 $("#price").css("color","red");
}
```

And the if statement should be inside your change function

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a input to be able to have a event on change.

So my suggestion is to add a input (you can remove the border to not look like a input), and add a class that applies the color red.

html

```
<input id="Input_id" class="ProductPrice VariationProductPrice" value="$42.00">
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Input_id').on('change', function () {
        $(this).addClass('red');
    });
})
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rgg3A/)**